# Compare req.body with a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I am trying to compare `req.body` with a string but it is not working. I have tried using `JSON.stringify(req.body)` but not working. `console.log(states)` gives ***"Minnesota"***. The `if statement` always returns the error message either if the input is Minnesota or not i.e. it always true. Posting the whole code will be too long and that is why I choose the one I think it is important. Sorry for the confusion. Please let me if you need me to provide more information. Thanks for your assistance.

***index.js***

```
var states = JSON.stringify(req.body.state_name);
if (states !== "Minnesota" || states !== "MINNESOTA") {
  res.render("insertme", {
    msg: "Error: Please Select Only Minnesota in State Field!"
  });
}
```

***ejs***

```
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;"> State Name
   <input id="state" type="text" name="state_name" placeholder="Please Only Select Minnesota">
</div>
```

Comment: did you include body parser? what is the value of `states`? Please post the code block where you `app.use` the bodyparser.

Comment: 1) Can you `console.log(states)` so we can see what the response looks like? 2) Use `if(states.toLowerCase() !== "minnesota")` 3) Perhaps try `if(states.toLowerCase().indexOf("minnesota") === -1)` in case there is some padding on the response.

Comment: @guzmonne as he already added the `body-parser` tag, I assumed that OP already added it somewhere but perhaps incorrectly.

Comment: You mentioned that you tried to do something, but it's not working... what exactly does not working mean? What were the inputs? what were the outputs? any errors?

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`? Because if your though was to use that to turn something into a string: that is _not_ what it does. It turns something into a _JSON string_, which is a _very_ different kind of string data. If it exists, just use `req.body.state_name` directly?

Comment: I use it directly @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and still the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your if test is will fail for Minnesota because you have an OR operator checking for != MINNESOTA.  Your if should be

```
if (states !== "Minnesota" && states !== "MINNESOTA") {  // use AND operator
```

or better:

```
if (states.toUpperCase() !== "MINNESOTA") {
```

Comment: It doesn't work. From the comments, I figure out that it is padding error from the response. I did it like `if(states.toLowerCase().indexOf("minnesota") === -1)` to close the padding and work just fine. This might help someone again. Thanks.